# Displaying data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add some data to a `JTable` and write to some file. The data is not being added to the table but is bring written to the file correctly.

Here is the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

  public class Layout extends JFrame {
        DefaultTableModel dtm;

        public Layout() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        p4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p5 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        l1 = new JLabel("Item");
        l2 = new JLabel("Price");
        l3 = new JLabel("Quantity");
        l4 = new JLabel("ReorderLevel");
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        tf4 = new JTextField();
        p3.add(l1);
        p3.add(tf1);
        p3.add(l2);
        p3.add(tf2);
        p3.add(l3);
        p3.add(tf3);
        p3.add(l4);
        p3.add(tf4);

        b1 = new JButton("Add");
        b2 = new JButton("Update");
        b3 = new JButton("Delete");
        b4 = new JButton("List");
        p4.add(b1);
        p4.add(b2);
        p4.add(b3);
        p4.add(b4);

        t = new JTable();
        t.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    //{null, null, null, null},
                    //{null, null, null, null},
                    //{null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Item", "Price", "Quantity", "Reorder"
                }
        ));
        sc = new JScrollPane(t);

        p5.add(sc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p2.add(p3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p2.add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(p5, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p1);

        pack();

        b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnaddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
        );   
    }                      `add button action`
        private void btnaddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
               String item = tf1.getText();
               String price = tf2.getText();
               String quantity=tf3.getText();
               String reorder=tf4.getText();


               try {


               String filename= "C:\\WINNT\\PROFILES\\palanisamyp\\workspace\\InventoryDBInfile\\Myfile.txt";


                       FileWriter myfile = new FileWriter(filename,true);

                        PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(myfile);
                        outStream.print(item);
                        outStream.print("|");
                        outStream.print(price);
                        outStream.print("|");
                        outStream.print(quantity);
                        outStream.print("|");
                        outStream.print(reorder);
                        outStream.print("\r\n");
                        outStream.close();

                            tf1.setText("");
                            tf2.setText("");
                            tf3.setText("");
                            tf4.setText("");
                            myfile.close(); 

              readFile();



               } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}


        }

        private void readFile()
        {
                BufferedReader br = null;

          try {

          String sCurrentLine;

          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\WINNT\\PROFILES\\palanisamyp\\workspace\\InventoryDBInfile\\Myfile.txt"));

          if (dtm.getRowCount() > 0) {
              for (int i = dtm.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                  dtm.removeRow(i);
              }
          }
          while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

          String item1=sCurrentLine.toString();

          String regexp = "[|]+";

          String[] lines = item1.split(regexp);

          Vector v = new Vector();  

                 String item2;
                 String price2;
                 String quantity2;
                 String reorder2;

                 item2=lines[0].toString();
                 price2=lines[1].toString();
                 quantity2=lines[2].toString();
                 reorder2=lines[3].toString();


                 v.add(item2);
                 v.add(price2);
                 v.add(quantity2);
                 v.add(reorder2);

                 dtm.toString();
                 dtm.addRow(v); 


          }

          } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
          try {
          if (br != null)br.close();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Layout().setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
    private JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
    private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4;
    private JScrollPane sc;
    private JTable t;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add data to the Jtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953512/how-to-add-data-to-the-jtable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you assign you table's dateModel to the new DefaultTableModel

```
 t.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{
                //{null, null, null, null},
                //{null, null, null, null},
                //{null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String[]{
                "Item", "Price", "Quantity", "Reorder"
            }
    ));
```

Instead of using your field `dtm`

```
DefaultTableModel dtm;
```

Try this:

```
 dtm = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    //{null, null, null, null},
                    //{null, null, null, null},
                    //{null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Item", "Price", "Quantity", "Reorder"
                }
        ));
  t.setModel(dtm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to see how to use model, renderer and editor in Java table.